# How to find number of times items and their combinations were purchased?

Tags: r, data.table, market-basket-analysis

I have a `data.table` showing which items a customer purchased. Each row represents one customer and each column one item. The table has same number of columns for each customer and the values in columns `item*` are either 1 or 0 based on whether customer purchased a given item. Simple version of the table looks like this:

```
data.table(customerID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
           item1 = c(1,0,0,1,1),
           item2 = c(1,0,1,1,1),
           item3 = c(1,0,0,0,1),
           item4 = c(0,1,1,1,1))
```

The table says that customer 1 purchased items 1,2,3 and item 3 was purchased by customers 1 and 5.

In real case the data.table has so many columns it would be impractical to refer to them by name in the code, but it would be ok to have the data in long format instead.

I need to find out how many times individual items were purhcased and how many times their combinations were purchased. In this case i would like to get something like:

```
item1 3
item2 4
item3 2
item4 4
item1;item2 3
item1;item3 2
item1;item4 1
...
(same for other combinations of length 2)
...
item1;item2;item3 2
item1;item2;item4 1

...
up to combinations of 4 items.
```

Moreover, i'll need for each customer a table indicating which combinations of products he or she purchased.

### Edit:

Thanks to three very useful answers, i know how to answer the first part of the question - i.e. calculate how many customers purchased certain combination. However, the second part remains unanswered. I would like to know which customers purchased which combination.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, since you say it has *"so many columns it would be impractical to refer to them by name"*, that suggests that your combinations of 4 will get exponentially more difficult to track. Can you quantify it somewhat? Even just 10 items gives you 210 combinations (`dim(combn(10,4))`). (All 1-4 combinations: `sum(sapply(1:4, function(i) ncol(combn(10,i))))` yields 385 total combinations; 20 items gives 6195 combinations.)

Comment: It's going to be a lot of combinations.

Comment: @r2evans Depends on whether thinking about it and not knowing what to do counts. But yea, i can extract all the possible combinations of length 1:N from the data.table column names and then for each of them group the data table by them and count the number of observations. I don't want to do it this way. As for number of combinations: well, there is about 100 items and about 60000 rows right now. I do not really care about items which were never purchased together, so that reduces the number of returned values a bit.

Comment: @sindri_baldur ups, true, i see that now

Comment: Unless you can *guarantee* a sparsely-filled matrix of items, 100 items can scale up to 4,087,975 combinations. I don't know your data, but it is often safer to program defensively against a "full-ish" dataset up front so that you don't out-scale your coding/setup. Over to you, I'm not dictating, just wondering.

Comment: @r2evans I wouldn't mind 4,087,975 combinations as i will select only those which are most relevant for me. But it's a good catch, i think i'll eventually simply focus on combinations up to certain lenght. Non of my customers bought all of the items anyway. Less than 10% bought more than 60 of them

Comment: still, combinations of length = 4 out of 100 items, results in 4,087,975 possible combos. Length = 3 gives 166,750 possible combos... I don't want to calculate >4 items ;-)

Comment: @Wimpel Fair enough, but i am not making all the combinations. I am interested only in those which occur in the dataset. Which is significantly less than all of the technically possible combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a completely base R option so converting the data to dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(df)
unique_product <- names(df[-1])

stack(unlist(sapply(seq_along(unique_product), function(x) 
     combn(unique_product, x, FUN = function(y) 
           setNames(sum(rowSums(df[y] == 1) == length(y)), 
            paste0(y, collapse = ";")), simplify = FALSE))))


#   values                     ind
#1       3                   item1
#2       4                   item2
#3       2                   item3
#4       4                   item4
#5       3             item1;item2
#6       2             item1;item3
#7       2             item1;item4
#8       2             item2;item3
#9       3             item2;item4
#10      1             item3;item4
#11      2       item1;item2;item3
#12      2       item1;item2;item4
#13      1       item1;item3;item4
#14      1       item2;item3;item4
#15      1 item1;item2;item3;item4
```

We create all combination of each unique product with `combn` and for every combination count how many of them occur together by subsetting the respective columns from dataframe.

---

To get the customers which unlocked certain combinations we can continue the same approach

```
stack(unlist(sapply(seq_along(unique_product), function(x) 
     combn(unique_product, x, FUN = function(y) {
      inds <- rowSums(df[x] == 1) == length(x)
      setNames(df$customerID[inds], 
             rep(paste0(y, collapse = ";"), sum(inds)))
             }, simplify = FALSE))))

#   values                     ind
#1       1                   item1
#2       1                   item2
#3       1                   item3
#4       1                   item4
#5       1             item1;item2
#6       4             item1;item2
#7       5             item1;item2
#8       1             item1;item3
#9       4             item1;item3
#10      5             item1;item3
#....
```

You can rename the columns if needed but here `values` are the Customer Id's and `ind` are the combinations which the respective customer unlocked.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good start. It seems to work, but it also is rather slow. I think i really, really underestimated how many rows i'll get if i tackle the problem in this way :D

Comment: @ira yes, as mentioned in the comments. It is going to be looooot of combinations...

Comment: Would you also know how to find out which customers unlocked each of the combinations?

Comment: @ira Updated the answer with that.

Answer (score 3):

A step by step approach using baseR and data.table

**sample data**

```
DT <- data.table(customerID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
           item1 = c(1,0,0,1,1),
           item2 = c(1,0,1,1,1),
           item3 = c(1,0,0,0,1),
           item4 = c(0,1,1,1,1))
```

**code**

```
#identify columns with items, grab their names
cols <- names(DT[,-1])
```

*in code below: set `1:length(cols)` to `1:n` if you want combinations of maximum of n products*

```
#put all combinations of items in a list
combos <- unlist( lapply( 1:length(cols), combn, x = cols, simplify = FALSE ), recursive = FALSE )

#calculate number of sold items per combo
l <- lapply( combos, function(x) {
  nrow( DT[ rowSums( DT[, x, with = FALSE ] ) == length( x ), ] )
})

#name the list based on the combo
names(l) <- lapply( combos, paste0, collapse = ";")
```

**output**

```
str( l )
```

> ```
> List of 15
> $ item1                  : int 3
> $ item2                  : int 4
> $ item3                  : int 2
> $ item4                  : int 4
> $ item1;item2            : int 3
> $ item1;item3            : int 2
> $ item1;item4            : int 2
> $ item2;item3            : int 2
> $ item2;item4            : int 3
> $ item3;item4            : int 1
> $ item1;item2;item3      : int 2
> $ item1;item2;item4      : int 2
> $ item1;item3;item4      : int 1
> $ item2;item3;item4      : int 1
> $ item1;item2;item3;item4: int 1
> ```

or create a data.table

```
as.data.table( as.matrix( unlist(l), ncol = 2, nrow = length(l) ), keep.rownames = TRUE )
```

> ```
> #                         rn V1
> # 1:                   item1  3
> # 2:                   item2  4
> # 3:                   item3  2
> # 4:                   item4  4
> # 5:             item1;item2  3
> # 6:             item1;item3  2
> # 7:             item1;item4  2
> # 8:             item2;item3  2
> # 9:             item2;item4  3
> #10:             item3;item4  1
> #11:       item1;item2;item3  2
> #12:       item1;item2;item4  2
> #13:       item1;item3;item4  1
> #14:       item2;item3;item4  1
> #15: item1;item2;item3;item4  1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some dirty code that allows you to set the parameter `n_items` which controls the maximum size of a bundle:

```
library(magrittr)
DT_melt <- DT[, melt(.SD, id.vars = "customerID", variable.factor = FALSE)
              ][value == 1
                ][, variable := as.integer(sub("item", "", variable))]
n_items <- 4L
keep_track <- list()
for (i in seq_len(n_items)) {
  combs <- combn(seq_len(n_items), i)
  keep_track[[i]] <- apply(combs, 2, function(x)  DT_melt[, all(x %in% variable), by = customerID]) %>%
    lapply(function(x) sum(x[[2]])) %>% 
    setNames(apply(combs, 2, function(x) paste(paste0("item", x), collapse = ";")))
}
unlist(keep_track)
```

Returns a named vector of counts:

```
#                   item1                   item2 
#                       3                       4 
#                   item3                   item4 
#                       2                       4 
#             item1;item2             item1;item3 
#                       3                       2 
#             item1;item4             item2;item3 
#                       2                       2 
#             item2;item4             item3;item4 
#                       3                       1 
#       item1;item2;item3       item1;item2;item4 
#                       2                       2 
#       item1;item3;item4       item2;item3;item4 
#                       1                       1 
# item1;item2;item3;item4 
#                       1
```